# T-Sql dateadd() How to fix overflow error

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm using the dateadd function in tsql and I'm getting an overflow error. Here is my code:

```
insert into dbo.PayPeriodLookups (PayPeriodEndDate, PayPeriodStartDate)
values
(20161015, dateadd(day, -13, '2016/10/15')),
(20161029, dateadd(day, -13, '2016/10/29')),
(20161112, dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/11/12')),
(20161126, dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/11/26')),
(20161210, dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/12/10')),
(20161224, dateadd(Day, -13, '2016/12/24')),
(20170107, dateadd(day, -13, '2017/01/07')),
(20170121, dateadd(day, -13, '2017/01/21'))
```

I keep getting this error when I try to execute this script:
*'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
The statement has been terminated.'*

Anyone know as to why I'm getting this error? I thought this was the way that the dateadd function worked...

Comment: Tip: Including the table schema with the column data types in the question is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with `DATEADD()`, this is an issue with the `PayPeriodEndDate` values you're inserting.  You're using `INT` values to represent the dates, when you should be wrapping them in single quotes.

You're trying to do an implicit cast from an `INT` to a `DATETIME`, which cannot be done the way you're doing it.  The correct way to represent dates is via `'yyyy-mm-dd'`.  Use the following instead:

```
Values
(Cast('2016-10-15' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2016-10-15')),
(Cast('2016-10-29' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2016-10-29')),
(Cast('2016-11-12' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2016-11-12')),
(Cast('2016-11-26' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2016-11-26')),
(Cast('2016-12-10' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2016-12-10')),
(Cast('2016-12-24' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2016-12-24')),
(Cast('2017-01-07' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2017-01-07')),
(Cast('2017-01-21' As DateTime), DateAdd(Day, -13, '2017-01-21'))
```

Comment: Just more readable (which I agree with), however you can Select cast('20161015' as date)

Comment: @Siyual--may be use `cast(.. as datetime)` to be more correct.

Comment: @vkp There shouldn't really be a need to `CAST` it, since the column is already a `DATETIME` datatype (as per the error).

Answer (score 1):

Either quote your int values as illustrated below

```
Declare @T1 table (PayPeriodEndDate datetime,PayPeriodStartDate datetime)
Insert Into @T1 values
('20161015', dateadd(day, -13, '2016/10/15')),
('20161029', dateadd(day, -13, '2016/10/29')),
('20161112', dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/11/12')),
('20161126', dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/11/26')),
('20161210', dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/12/10')),
('20161224', dateadd(Day, -13, '2016/12/24')),
('20170107', dateadd(day, -13, '2017/01/07')),
('20170121', dateadd(day, -13, '2017/01/21'))

Select * from @T1
```

Or cast your int values as varchar(8)

```
Declare @T2 table (PayPeriodEndDate datetime,PayPeriodStartDate datetime)
Insert Into @T2 values
(cast(20161015 as varchar(8)), dateadd(day, -13, '2016/10/15')),
(cast(20161029 as varchar(8)), dateadd(day, -13, '2016/10/29')),
(cast(20161112 as varchar(8)), dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/11/12')),
(cast(20161126 as varchar(8)), dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/11/26')),
(cast(20161210 as varchar(8)), dateadd(DAY, -13, '2016/12/10')),
(cast(20161224 as varchar(8)), dateadd(Day, -13, '2016/12/24')),
(cast(20170107 as varchar(8)), dateadd(day, -13, '2017/01/07')),
(cast(20170121 as varchar(8)), dateadd(day, -13, '2017/01/21'))

Select * from @T2
```